# Node 'writefile' Add Instead of Replace

Tags: node.js, fs

Is there any way for me to write to a file and have it simply add any new data instead of replacing the previous data?

Currently I'm using CasperJS to extract a list of items on a page and I'm using fs.write on Node to save it.

I'd like to make one large list and add to it everytime I run the script instead of having separate entries every time.

Alternatively, is there any way to combine multiple HTML files in Node?

Comment: You could use [`fs.appendFile`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_appendfile_file_data_options_callback) instead.

Comment: If you submit that as an answer I'll 'best answer' it :) Exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`fs.appendFile`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_appendfile_file_data_options_callback) instead of `fs.write`. From the docs:

> Asynchronously append data to a file, creating the file if it does not yet exist.